# DELL Latitude 7300 doesn't recognize monitors via thunderbolt WD19TB on linux

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, dell, thunderbolt, usb-c

I just bought a DELL Latitude 7300 with a thunderbolt WD19T and two monitors of 24'  P2419HC. I installed ubuntu 18.04 but I'm having some issues with Dell Thunderbolt Dock WD19TB, 180W.

So my Ethernet and USB (keyboard and mouse) are working fine but both monitors are not recognized by Ubuntu 18.04. I've tried a lot of things but nothing has worked. Does anyone have any idea what to do ?

I use mainly Ubuntu 18.04 with `name - a`

```
Linux <username> 5.3.0-40-generic #32~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 3 14:05:59 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

and `boltctl list`

```
Dell WD19TB Thunderbolt Dock
   ├─ type:          peripheral
   ├─ name:          WD19TB Thunderbolt Dock
   ├─ vendor:        Dell
   ├─ uuid:          number
   ├─ status:        authorized
   │  ├─ domain:     domain
   │  └─ authflags:  boot
   ├─ authorized:    mer. 04 mars 2020 10:04:13 UTC
   ├─ connected:     mer. 04 mars 2020 10:04:13 UTC
   └─ stored:        mar. 03 mars 2020 12:21:41 UTC
      ├─ policy:     auto
      └─ key:        no
```

Thank you for your help